# How to Show gauge / SpeedView on iOS (Xcode)

Tags: ios

I am new to iOS Development, I have an android App which has gauges in it.
Same way I want to develop iOS App with same functionality.
The library I used in Android was 
https://github.com/anastr/SpeedView
Is there any similar library for iOS ?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try [SmartGauge](https://github.com/rameezhandel/SmartGauge)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah in iOS also there are libraries for GaugeView. Try these libraries GDGauge(https://github.com/saeid/GDGauge), WMGaugeView(https://github.com/ahmgsk/ios-GaugeView).